# Javascript toggle checkbox

Tags: javascript, html, checkbox

I need to toggle all buttons with a single function. Function needs to toggle all checkboxes in the document as my checkboxes are freestanding and not part of a form.

I currently have this, but it is not working properly. I get `syntax error: syntax error` in my firefox console.

```
    checked=false;
    function checkedAll() {
        var c = new Array();
        c = doc.getElementsByTagName('input');
        if (checked == false){
            checked = true;
        }else{
            checked = false;
        }
        for (var i = 0; i < c.length; i++){
            if (c[i].type == 'checkbox'){
                c[i].checked = checked;
            }
        }
    }
```

How can I fix my code?

Thanks

Comment: can u create a jsfiddle for the above code

Comment: typo.. doc should be document. sorry. voting to close.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I check a checkbox with jQuery or JavaScript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/426258/how-do-i-check-a-checkbox-with-jquery-or-javascript)

Comment: Answer foudn by the OP itself.

Comment: FYI, your `if` statement can be replaced with just `checked = !checked;`. The `!` character negates your `checked` variable. If `checked` was equal to `true`, `!checked` would equal `false`.

Comment: the syntax error is about 'doc'; should be 'document'.

        c = doc.getElementsByTagName('input');

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Two main items to refactor.  First, instead of `doc` it must be `document`.  Second instead of relying on a global just pass in a boolean to determine whether or not to check the checkboxes.

```
function checkedAll(isChecked) {
    var c = document.querySelectorAll('input[type="checkbox"]');

    for (var i = 0; i < c.length; i++){
        c[i].checked = isChecked;
    }
}
```

**JS Fiddle:** http://jsfiddle.net/Jvnfm/107/

Answer (score 2):

You can alternatively perform the following for each checkbox element:

```js
    c[i].click();
```

This version will trigger any associated event handlers associated with that element.

Comment: bad idea if the script is being run by an onclick event