# Toggle Checkbox using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, if-statement

I had this working, but I didnt save and cannot replicate. I am trying to toggle checkboxes using `if else`. What am I doing wrong.

What I thought would work:

```
function myForm() {
    var inputs = document.getElementsByTagName("input");
    for(var i = 0; i < inputs.length; i++) {
        if(inputs[i].type == "checkbox") { 
            if(inputs[i].checked = false) {
                inputs[i].checked = true; 
            } else {
                if(inputs[i].checked = true) {
                    inputs[i].checked = false; 
                }   
            }
        }  
    } 
}
```

Comment: why aren't you using toggle()?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Javascript toggle checkbox](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19155423/javascript-toggle-checkbox)

Comment: @Harry thank you I will look at that function

Comment: @4castle Yes it should be input, sorry. When using your code, do I still need to put `=true/false`?

Comment: @ceuskervin You don't. Using the not `!` operator, it will assign the opposite of the current value, so if it is currently `true` it will be assigned `false`, and if it is `false` it will be assigned `true`.

Comment: thank you this worked perfectly @4castle

Comment: @Harry `toggle()` is jQuery correct?

Comment: yes it is @ceuskervin

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Single equals is assignment, double/triple equals is for equality.  You need to use double or triple equals in your if/else block.

```
    if(inputs[i].checked == false) {
        inputs[i].checked = true; 
    }
    else {
        if(inputs[i].checked == true) {
            inputs[i].checked = false; 
         }   
    }
```

Comment: It is a good practice to always use `===`/`!==` instead of `==`/`!=` when comparing to `Boolean`, or to perform type coercion manually only when you need to.

Comment: In fact, the if statement inside the else statement is completely unnecessary. Just do  `inputs[i].checked = false;` inside the else.

Comment: @Farside In this case they might as well use `==` to save bytes, because `checked` will always be a boolean. But yes, it is good practice.

Comment: I was actually planning on using triple equal as I wrote the opening sentence...not sure what happened.

Comment: Thank you. All of my checkboxes are toggling, except for the checkbox that initiates the toggling.

Comment: @ceuskervin That's because it's being toggled twice. Once by the click, and once by your code. Whatever code is capturing the checkbox click event needs to `return false` or use `e.preventDefault`.

Comment: Couldn't you just say `inputs[i].checked = !(inputs[i].checked)` instead of using the `if`/`else`?

Comment: Yeah that should work well, this answer was more to show op why his code didn't work.

Answer (score 78):

It can be easier:

```
inputs[i].checked = !inputs[i].checked;
```

Answer (score 41):

How about using an operator, that is defined to toggle booleans using 1 as second operand?

```
inputs[i].checked ^= 1;
```

This uses the [XOR](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exclusive_or) [Compound assigment operator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operators_in_C_and_C%2B%2B#Compound_assignment_operators), and it toggles booleans because in formal boolean math `¬A ≡ A ^ 1`.
(Read as: "Not(`¬`) A is equivalent(`≡`) to A XOR(`^`)ed with literal 1")

It also doesn't require using `inputs[i]` a second time.

2020 update:
You can also eliminate the `for` loop and all those `var`s by using the [`forEach`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) function to iterate over the checkboxes, reducing your function body to:

```
document.querySelectorAll('input[type="checkbox"]').forEach(e => e.checked ^= 1);
```

Comment: Whoa! Never seen that before. What is that operator ^=?

Comment: `^` is the XOR operator; `a ^ b` is true if `a` and `b` have different values, or false otherwise. `a ^= true` (equivalent to `a = a ^ true`) evaluates to `false` if `a` is `true` and `true` if `a` is `false`.

Comment: While this "works", I don't think it's a good idea - using bitwise operators when not needed makes for less readable, more opaque code, as you can see by the first comment. It will confuse people. Readable code is more important than concise code, unless you're code golfing.

Comment: I disagree. Back in the day XOR was covered in the first week of CS. If "XOR 1" is "opaque" or "unreadable" to a non-beginner programmer, they should probably never go near any kind of performance, or security critical code.

Answer (score 1):

Another correct answer could be:

```
inputs[i].checked = input.checked ? false : true;
```

Comment: I like this one. The answers with the ^= operator work, but not all developers will understand it. This pattern is more widely known.

Answer (score 0):

I thought I would add to this since it led me to an answer I was seeking for checking all checkboxes with bookmarklet. Using the bitwise operator worked like a charm in IE 11 and Chrome. Haven't tried it in other browsers.

```
javascript:(function(){var chbxs=document.querySelectorAll('input');for(i in chbxs){chbxs[i].checked^=1;}})();
```